# Prevent a button from sending text to a div if no text was entered in text box - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not using a form but have a text area. I want to ensure that blank messages can not be sent if the text area is empty and the button to send the message is pressed.

Comment: `if (!text || text.length === 0) return;` It would help if you include the `function` used for sending, as well as the `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add an empty value check inside your `sendText` function:

```
function sendText() {
    var textValue = document.getElementById('post_box').value;

    if (!textValue || textValue.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

The `return` statement will keep your function from executing any further, as the check will not succeed for an empty textValue. You could present a message to the user in this case saying the textfield is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code related to this? You would simply need to check the trimmed length of your `<textarea>` to see if any content was present and then send your message :

```
if(!message || message.value.trim().length === 0){
      alert('A message is required.')
}
else{
      // Send your message
}
```

A complete example might look like :

```
<textarea id='check-me'></textarea>
<br />
<button onclick='sendMessage();'>Send Message</button>
<script>
function sendMessage(){
  // Get your textarea and check it's content
  var message = document.getElementById('check-me');
  // Check the message
  if(!message || message.value.trim().length === 0){
      alert('A message is required.')
  }
  else{
      // Send your message
  }
}
</script>
```